# How to explode row list into multiple cumulative lists?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Firstly I did a groupby operation: `df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list).reset_index(name='b')`

```
a b
A 1
A 2
B 5
B 5
B 4
C 6
```

Resulting in this df:

```
a b
A [1,2]
B [5,5,4]
C [6]
```

Now I want to explode these lists into multiple cumulative lists by row.

```
a b
A [1]
A [1,2]
B [5]
B [5,5]
B [5,5,4]
C [6]
```

Comment: Maybe it is not a good idea to expect any answers without providing us with the dataframe itself. I have run the code you provided on a dataframe such as the first cell in this question. There is an error with this dataframe.

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"], 'b':[1,2,5,5,4,6]})```
```df.groupby("a")["b"].apply(list).reset_index(name='b')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 1st convert the cell value to `list` then we can do `cumsum`

```
df['out'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x : [x]).groupby(df['a']).apply(lambda x : x.cumsum() )
Out[382]: 
0          [1]
1       [1, 2]
2          [5]
3       [5, 5]
4    [5, 5, 4]
5          [6]
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As `DataFrame.expanding()` seems only to work on numeric data, I resort to this nested list comprehension:

```
df['b'] = [subdf['b'].tolist()[:i+1] 
           for group, subdf in df.groupby('a')
           for i in range(subdf.shape[0])]

print(df)

   a          b
0  A        [1]
1  A     [1, 2]
2  B        [5]
3  B     [5, 5]
4  B  [5, 5, 4]
5  C        [6]
```